# Unity launcher for Intellij duplicate after application loading

Tags: unity, launcher, intellij

I create a launcher for Ingtellij Idea by writing a custom .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=13.3
Name=Intellij Idea
Comment=
Type=Application
Categories=Developoment,IDE
Exec=/home/sravinda/idea-IU-135.690/bin/idea.sh
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/sravinda/idea-IU-133.331/bin/idea.png
Name[en_US]=Intellij Idea
```

I put it to *~/.local/share/applications*. I get and launcher and I added that to the unity side bar. 
When I launch the application another icon appear in the side bar. Which is different from other applications. There same icon represent the launched application with small bracket on left of the icon. Any one have idea why is that.

Comment: Isnt it `usr/bin/intlellij` for `Exec=`?

Comment: Nope I extract it to my home directory. It doesn't matter r8?

Comment: Most likely the same cause as this one http://askubuntu.com/a/465308/72216 (third cause). To make a nice configuration, I would create a directory ~/bin, create a link to the application: `ln -sf /home/sravinda/idea-IU-135.690/bin/idea /home/sravinda/bin/idea`, make the application file `idea.sh`executable, and simply run it by the command `idea` in the `Exec=` line. Then add the line at the end of the file's content: `StartupWMClass=idea`. You may have to log out /in.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**You can get Intellij to generate the icon in /usr/share/applications for you to copy to your launcher:**

1. Open a terminal, in idea/bin folder
2. Start IntelliJ with `./idea.sh`
3. Tools -> Generate Desktop Entry [image]
4. Close IntelliJ
5. In the terminal, start nautilus as admin (`gksudo nautilus`)
6. Go to /usr/share/applications
7. Drag the new icon for IntelliJ to your launcher

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by adding 'StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea' to the desktop file. Got help from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36434/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-icons-for-launched-java-programs-in-the-launcher).

BTW colleague provide a easier way of creating a unity launcher for Intellij.

1. Go to tools -> Generate Desktop Entry from Intellj IDEA ( it crates the desktop file for you)
2. Search in from dash, run and lock it to the launcher.